# Not able to change the role and delete aria-haspopup attribute when using Dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using react-bootstrap 0.32.4 and i am creating Custom Dropdown.
Please refer the code.

```
 <Dropdown
            id={id}
            open={open}
            onToggle={this.onToggleHandler}>
            <Dropdown.Toggle noCaret>
                <DropdownInput
                    {...rest}
                />
            </Dropdown.Toggle>
            <DropdownMenu bsRole="menu">
                <RootCompCloseWrapper
                    disabled={!open}
                    handleRootClose={this.handleRootClose}
                    event="click"
                >
                    <DropdownContent legendText={legendText}>
                        {children}
                    </DropdownContent>
                </RootCompCloseWrapper>
            </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
```

When i see the developer console the element gets displayed as

```
<div class="dropdown btn-group">
<button id="dd-guest-type" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" type="button" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default">
    <label class="floating-label">Please select</label>
    <label class="floating-value">Selected Value</label>
</button>
```

Please suggest how to change the role attribute and remove aria-haspopup attribute.

Comment: Have you tried overriding it with standard javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you can't.

The `aria-haspopup` and `role` attributes are [hard coded in the react-bootstrap DropdownToggle component](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v0.32.4/src/DropdownToggle.js#L45-L50):

```
  <Component
    {...props}
    role="button"
    className={classNames(className, bsClass)}
    aria-haspopup
    aria-expanded={open}
  >
```

I'd actually question why you want to do this though. Presumably the developers who created react-bootstrap, and the users of it, have designed this component to work in a way that suits then necessary accessibility standards for the controls that it provides. If you're trying to customise the DOM then I could see a valid case to want to customise these attributes, I suppose. If you think you have a valid use case to need to customise these then I suggest you [open an issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues) on the GitHub repository.

Comment: i want to change the role from button to combobox is there any way i can achieve this because of accessibility issue.

Comment: Again, please be more descriptive about why you want to change it. If there’s a bug in the code then you should change the attribute directly in the package, but perhaps your interpretation of it being a bug is different from the accessibility standards that were used for the development of that package